# Problems with displaying image in portlet using jsf

Tags: jsf, liferay, portlet

I need some help with showing images in my portlet. I have images somewhere on
HDD. I wrote servlet ImageServlet with doGet() method. I registered servlet
in web.xml with mapping /images/*.

The problem begins when i try to show image:

`<h:graphicImage url="/images/image.png" />`

The doGet() method in servlet is not called. HTML output I get is:

`<img src="/PortletName/images/image.png"/>`

However when I'm using other tag, for example:

`<jsp:include file="/images/image.png"/>`

doGet() in ImageServlet is called (it doesn't work
obviously, but it shows that servlet is registered correctly).

I tried mapping /PortletName/images/*, but it didn't help. And I can't write url without '/' in the beginning (I get an exception - Liferay
forbids it).

Am I missing something while calling servlet from h:graphicImage? Or is there any way to get rid of /PortletName/ in the generated HTML? Or is there other way to display image (using include or something)?

Help would be appreciated :)

Edit:
 JSF 1.1; DTD portlet application 4.3.0; portlet-app_1_0.xsd; org.apache.portals.bridges.portletfilter.FilterPortlet

Comment: What is the Portlet version? What is the JSF version? What JSF Portlet  bridge (and version) are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it. I used Liferay PortalDelegateServlet:
http://longgoldenears.blogspot.com/2008/03/portaldelegateservlet-servlet-session.html

and I used `<img>` tag.